# PhoneGap Push Notification shows message in notification bar when screen is locked

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

```
onNotificationGCM: function (e) {

         // alert('onNotificationGCM');
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                var regID=e.regid;
                //Call postGCMRegistration inthe hosLib.js Class to send RegID to Server
                postGCMRegistration(regID);

              //  alert('registration id = '+regID);

            }
        break;

        case 'message':

            if (e.foreground) {
                // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                if (e.message == "ignitionON") {
                    //   alert("ignitionON");
                    ignitionON();
                }
                if (e.message == "movementON") {
                    // alert("movementON");
                    MovementStarted();
                }
                if (e.message == "ignitionOFF") {
                    // alert("ignitionOFF");
                    ignitionOFF();
                }

            }
         //alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
        break;

        case 'error':
          //alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
        break;

        default:
        //  alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
    }
},
};
```

This is my code for setting up Push Notification in my Android app, it is working perfectly fine.

The only thing I don't want to show is the received push messages on the notification bar, when my screen is locked or the app is not opened, that message stays on the notification bar (but it doesn't show anything in notification bar if app is open on the main screen).

Any Solution for this ?